# Is there a way to put the time above the date with the Gnome Extension, Dash to Panel?

Tags: gnome-shell, panel, 18.10, gnome-shell-extension, clock

Just to be clear, I have no idea if this is the right place for this or anything. I just want help. I'm also on the mobile site so some important things may not be visible.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.10, have enabled the date, installed Gnome Tweaks and the extension, Dash to Panel.